# Delay in Datadog reporting the go_expvar

Tags: datadog

I have `datadog agent` running on ubuntu 14.04. And I am trying to monitor page views for the go apps as mentioned in the [link](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/instrument-go-apps-expvar-datadog/). I have checked everything yaml also it is valid. But still it doesn't even report for upto go_expvar data even after 30 min. I checked in the dashboard it says Last check 29 mins ago. Can anyone tell me how to debug this or reduce this time

Comment: Check out `/var/log/datadog/collector.log` logfile, you should be able to see if something is wrong

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Agent's info command to see if the check is reporting correctly:

https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/203764635

If the Agent Status shows the check is reporting correctly but your metrics are still not reporting you can contact support@datadoghq.com and they can troubleshoot this issue further.

Hope this helps!